# First-order modified Patankar–Euler scheme (MPE)

Tags: finite-difference, implicit-methods, explicit-methods

Is the first-order Modified Patankar–Euler scheme (MPE) an implicit or explicit method?
Is there an open-source code implementing the MPE scheme for a system of ODEs?